# Firefox in an "app mode"

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to have a configuration of firefox to fake an "app mode". More precisely, I would like to have no navbar and disable the keyboard shortcuts like Ctrl-L, Ctrl-Q, etc ...

I am running firefox in the i3wm and it automatically starts in full screen using i3 configuration trick:

```
exec_always --no-startup-id i3-msg 'workspace 1; exec script.sh'
for_window [class=".*"] fullscreen enable
```

The script opens firefox with `/usr/bin/firefox -new-instance url`

But the user should not be able to change url or add a tab with Ctrl-T. So is it possible to disable the navbar (like the bookmark bar) and disable the shortcuts. That would put firefox in a sort of "app mode" where navigation would be controlled by the buttons available on the web page only! Is there a way?

Plus, upon deployment of the webapp, I would like to have those settings ready. How can I store the configuration and replicate it on the deployed machine?

Comment: You want to achieve what is usually called a _kiosk mode_, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [userChrome.css](https://www.howtogeek.com/334716/how-to-customize-firefoxs-user-interface-with-userchrome.css/), one can remove the nav-bar and the tab-bar with the following code:

```
#nav-bar {
    display: none !important;
}

#TabsToolbar {
  visibility: collapse !important;
}
```

This nevertheless does not disable the keyboard shortcuts, and in particular when one presses Ctrl-T it creates a new tab in which one cannot set a url since the navbar is not available.

[Here](https://github.com/Timvde/UserChrome-Tweaks) is a useful link for some tweaks to be found!